# Save persistent data easily and read in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, persistence

Wanted to ask if something Objective-C exists to store data on the device quickly and also recover other than sqlite android also have this option:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

    int IdUsuario = prefs.getInt("IdUsuario",0);
    int IdTipoAuto = prefs.getInt("IdTipoAuto",0);
```

There is something in Objective-C so fast that you can always read without problem or change at any time, even if you close the app Information always persist in app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` / Core Data / a file on disk (either plist or binary) / the keychain

There are many options depending on exactly what your data is, how you're going to use it and how long it should survive for...

Comment: intente con esto  // Store the data
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    
    [defaults setObject:@"fecha" forKey:fecha];
    
    [defaults synchronize];
    
    NSLog(@"Data saved");   y de leerlo con esto     // Get the stored data before the view loads
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    
    NSString *firstName = [defaults objectForKey:@"fecha"]; pero no funciono al cerrar la app y abrirla de nuevo aparece nil